# Extracting RGB color histogram for an image using C# and EmguCV

Tags: c#, c++, emgucv

I am trying to extract RGB color Histogram for an image using C# (or C++) and Emgu CV. Current:

```
static double[] colorHistogram(Image<Bgr, Byte> img, int rStep, int gStep, int bStep)
{
     double[] histogram = null;
     return histogram;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Use the already available function [CalcHist](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0-alpha/document/html/32842749-8997-db6c-a271-7bc4c6ee93c4.htm) in EmguCV!

**C#:**

```
public static void CalcHist(
    IInputArray images,
    int[] channels,
    IInputArray mask,
    IOutputArray hist,
    int[] histSize,
    float[] ranges,
    bool accumulate
)
```

**C++:**

```
public:
static void CalcHist(
    IInputArray^ images, 
    array<int>^ channels, 
    IInputArray^ mask, 
    IOutputArray^ hist, 
    array<int>^ histSize, 
    array<float>^ ranges, 
    bool accumulate
)
```

There you go!